# How to Use React Toggle Inside Map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, map-function

I'm trying to use a toggle inside of a map function. I thought I had it, but there's clearly something wrong with my logic. When I click on some of the toggle items within the map, I have to click on them twice in order to see the change. It seems to happen when I toggle one item to true, then immediately toggle another item to true. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-hertz-srgew

And the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [prodToggle, setProdToggle] = useState(false);
  const [partToggle, setPartToggle] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("./data.json").then((res) => {
      setPeople(res.data.people);
    });
  }, []);

  const onAddProdSelect = () => {
    const updatedProdToggle = !prodToggle;
    setProdToggle(updatedProdToggle);
  };

  const onAddPartSelect = (i) => {
    const updatedToggle = !partToggle;
    setPartToggle(updatedToggle);
    const updatedData = people.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          itemPartToggle: updatedToggle
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setPeople(updatedData);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div onClick={() => onAddProdSelect()}>
        <p>{prodToggle ? "Red" : "Blue"}</p>
      </div>
      {people.map((person, i) => (
        <div onClick={() => onAddPartSelect(i)} key={i}>
          <p>{person.itemPartToggle ? person.name : person.age}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're sharing the one toggle state with all of your person objects by having the `partToggle` state. Instead, keep the toggle state on each object (like you are currently doing with `itemPartToggle`), and use that to determine what the toggle value should change to for that particular object that you clicked on:

```js
const onAddPartSelect = (i) => {
    const updatedData = people.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          itemPartToggle: !item.itemPartToggle // use the flipped version of the current toggle state for the current item
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setPeople(updatedData);
};
```

See example below:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([{"id":"1","name":"Bob","age":"21"},{"id":"2","name":"Ed","age":"45"},{"id":"3","name":"Mary","age":"32"},{"id":"4","name":"Tom","age":"76"}]); // hardcoding data for example
  const [prodToggle, setProdToggle] = useState(false);

  const onAddProdSelect = () => {
    const updatedProdToggle = !prodToggle;
    setProdToggle(updatedProdToggle);
  };

  const onAddPartSelect = (i) => {
    const updatedData = people.map((item, idx) => {
      if (idx === i) {
        return {
          ...item,
          itemPartToggle: !item.itemPartToggle
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setPeople(updatedData);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div onClick={() => onAddProdSelect()}>
        <p>{prodToggle ? "Red" : "Blue"}</p>
      </div>
      {people.map((person, i) => (
        <div onClick={() => onAddPartSelect(i)} key={i}>
          <p>{person.itemPartToggle ? person.name : person.age}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @typeyes - Did this answer your question in the end?